# Why is the work here positive and are we using 2nd law for this conclusion?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I am reading a popular article and in one of the lines it says that :

"To illustrate this point, consider the familiar gas-and-piston
setup, in which the gas of N = 10^23 molecules begins in a state of thermal equilibrium inside
a container enclosed by adiabatic walls. If the piston is rapidly pushed into the gas and then
pulled back to its initial location, there will be a **net increase in the internal energy of the gas**.
That is
W > 0
where W denotes the work performed by the agent that manipulates the piston.
"

what I am confused about is why is it saying that there will be a net increase in the internal energy of the gas??
I do get this intutively that there will be a net increase in the internal energy as the process is irreversible and so when my piston will come back to its original position there will be some energy lost to the system (had the process been reversible the energy given by me and taken by me will be equal and so net energy given by me will be zero but for irreversible process it wont be equal and overall I will give some energy.)

It all makes sense but can someone prove the mathematically using 2nd law. I believe that there will be some use of second law.

Comment: The internal energy of an ideal gas is a state function of only its temperature, $du=c_v dT $ and thus, if we return to the starting point, the change should be zero, which comes from the definition of a state variable.

Comment: @User198 The problem statement says the piston is returned to its initial "location". That only means the system is returned to initial volume not  its initial state.  The increase in internal energy means there is more compression work than expansion work. I believe the OP is asking for a second law explanation of this.

Comment: “If the piston is rapidly pushed into the gas and then
pulled back to its initial location”. Point of clarification. Is the piston also rapidly pulled back? My answer assumes gradually so it is reversible. Only then can we use first law. Otherwise you can only use second law as Chet Miller has shown in his correct answer. I m curious, why haven’t you accepted it?

Comment: @BobD Yes, I believe that it is pulled back with the same speed as it was pushed.I am sorry But I was busy with a presentation, but I have accepted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any first-law basis for saying that the work done on the gas is positive since we do not know how the externally applied force varies as the volume changes (without applying the laws of Newtonian Fluid dynamics).  We can't integrate the externally applied force over the volume change to determine the amount of work or even if it is positive.  In this respect, I differ with the other two answers, and must conclude that the second law has to be used.

Since the rapid expansion and compression constitutes an irreversible (presumed adiabatic) process, the entropy of the gas (presumed ideal) must increase.  For the overall process in which the initial and final volumes are equal, we therefore have from the 2nd law that $$\Delta S=nC_v\ln{(T_f/T_i)}>0$$So, $$T_f>T_i$$ and $$\Delta U=nC_v(T_f-T_i)>0$$So it follows from the second law of thermodynamics that the work done on the gas is positive.

Comment: The OP doesn’t really say the expansion is rapid. If the expansion back to the original volume is reversible I think we can use the first law only. Even if it’s not reversible too, but I’d have to try it.

Comment: @BobD “If the piston is pulled back rapidly…”

Comment: I can't find that quote. I see " then pulled back to its initial location" . I guess it could be interpreted as pulled back rapidly, but I left it open in composing my answer. Would you agree if it were pulled back reversibly we could determine the increase in internal energy by first law only?

Comment: @BobD  Oh, I got confused and extracted that quote from one of the other answers.    With regard to the increase in internal energy, we could get it only of the force in the compression part is constant (or if we somehow control the force to be a higher value than the reversible compression.  Otherwise ce could only say that the increase in internal energy during the compression stroke is greater than the decrease in internal energy during the expansion stroke.

Comment: Yes, if you specify the the external pressure vs volume. The work is precisely quantified.

Comment: For a reversible adiabatic process, $\Delta S = 0$

Comment: @Chet Miller I understood your explanation but why are you using ΔS=nCvln(Tf/Ti) formula for an irreversible process , I believe that this expression was derived from the assumption of reversible process (dS=dQ/T)  and so we can't use this form( ln(Tf/Ti) ) of the function for ΔS , I get the intution that We have to conclude Tf>Ti from ΔS > 0, but then we can't rigorously say that ΔU > 0.I might be overlooking something; please help clarify my doubt

Comment: @ChetMiller I got it thanks. Since S and U are state functions this analysis will be valid for reversible process too where initial and ending points are the same for the reversible and irreversible process.Thanks a Lot .

Comment: @BobD I think that entropy change for 1 and 2 will be different  as the final states for these 2 processes will be different.

Comment: @ChetMiller I’ve deleted my comments after realizing your answer only shows the second law proves the final temperature (and therefore internal energy) must increase, but not by how much, as we only know the final volume.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am confused about is why is it saying that there will be a net
> increase in the internal energy of the gas?
>
> It all makes sense but can someone prove the mathematically using 2nd
> law. I believe that there will be some use of second law.

It is saying this simply because the compression work is greater than the expansion work, i.e., $W_{net}\gt0$. Then, given $Q=0$, if follows from the first law that $\Delta U\gt0$. There is no need to consider the second law to reach this conclusion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any need to invoke the Second Law here. When the piston is pushed in, the environment does work on the gas and the internal energy of the gas increases. If the piston is pulled out rapidly, then the gas thereafter undergoes adiabatic free expansion. The internal energy doesn't change in this expansion, so there was a net increase in internal energy of the gas.

Of course, we could bring the Second Law to bear and discuss entropy production and irreversibility in the free expansion step, but I don't see this as essential to the question at hand.